# Android UI requirement

Tags: android-widget

I have UI requirement shown below:

```
|------------------------|
|Header-1                |
|     Checkbox1[]        |
|     Checkbox2[]        | 
|     Checkbox3[]        |
|------------------------|
|Header-2                |
|     Checkbox1 []       |
|     Checkbox2 []       |
|     Checkbox3 []       |
```

and so on clicking below button.
`BUTTON  ->` clicking on this button on bottom will create header and 3 checkbox everytime. How can i achieve this? This is very urgent. I can not take these in XML laypout as these need to be added dynamically on runtime.

If possible, Please provide any sample code and guide me.

Thanks,
Rachana

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847561/android-build-dynamic-form-from-code

Answer (score 0):

You should create a listView containing rows defined by a layout having :

> - a linear layout containing a textView with Header-1 (and so on) as text
> - another linearLayout containing three checkboxes.

You will create an **arrayAdapter** with a list of strings representing different values for Header-1 (I guess checkboxes will have same values all the time).

Adding a click listener (**onClickListener**) on your button. This listener will add an item to the arrayList used by the adapter to add new items in /remove items from your listview when your arrayList is modified (calling **notifyDataSetChanged()**) to refresh the listView.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, Thank you for your quick response. Can you please send me code?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, Please send me code, it is very urgent, I am working on weekends for my project release and have many things to do in plate, If possible send me the code. I will be great full to you.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I managed to display UI as per your suggestion, but now my problem is i am not able to find out which row chcekbox belongs when i clicked on checkbox. Lets say I clicked on first checkbox of second listbox item so i should somehow get that checkbox we clicked belongs to second listbox item